# jQuery Masked Input Plugin не корректно работает на мобильных устройствах Android

Tags: javascript, jquery, inputmask, mask

В форме установлена маска номера телефона. На десктопе и ios работает нормально во всех браузерах, на android отображается маска, но цифры не вводятся и курсор переходит к следующей цифре. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? freetraining.footbik.com.ua

Comment: Проверил с One+ - всё работает корректно.
Только я бы полю поставил tel так будет лучше

Comment: Форма во всплывающем окне не корректно работает. Та которая на первом экране нормально. Извините, забыл это уточнить.

Comment: Зачем две маски на одно поле? 
у вас в main.js стоит маска по полю js-phone и вы еще сверху одну маску. Удалить одну из масок

Answer (score 0):

Убрал maxlength для input, к которому была привязана маска, и всё заработало